# Multiplicativity of the Divisor Function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

I have this proof of the multiplicativity of the divisor function (I'm actually not sure if that is the correct name for it, since I'm studying it in german).
I already know that $d(p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_r^{e_r})=(e_1+1)\cdots(e_r+1)$. Here's the proof:

Let $d:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ with
$$n\mapsto \sum_{d\in\mathbb{N},\:d|n}1$$
be the divisor function.

Let $m=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_r^{e_r}$ and $n=q_1^{t_1}\cdots q_s^{t_s}$ where $p_i$ and $q_i$ are pairwise diffrent prime numbers. Then the following equalities hold:

$$d(m\cdot n)$$
$$=d\big((p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_r^{e_r})\cdot(q_1^{t_1}\cdots q_s^{t_s})\big)$$
$$=d(p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_r^{e_r}\cdot q_1^{t_1}\cdots q_s^{t_s})$$
$$=(e_1+1)\cdots(e_r+1)\cdot(t_1+1)\cdots(t_s+1)$$
$$=d(p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_r^{e_r})\cdot d(q_1^{t_1}\cdots q_s^{t_s})$$
$$=d(m)\cdot d(n)$$

Can anyone tell me if the proof provided is correct? It seems to be a bit too simple but I can't find any mistakes. Thank you for helping in advance.

Comment: Perfectly correct.  And "divisor function" is a good term.  Well...technically, any of the functions $\sigma_i(n)=\sum_{d\,|\,n} d^i$ are sometimes called divisor functions.  But if you speak of "$\textit {the}$ divisor function" you almost always mean the number of divisors, $\sigma_0(n)$.